# Как правильно чекать радиокнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть 2 блока радиокнопок в форме. По умолчанию ни одна радиокнопка не выбрана, поэтому я решил чекнуть первый вариант в каждом блоке скриптом:

```js
$('.radio').each(function(){
  $(this).find('input').first().attr('checked', 'checked');
})
```

Это работает. Добавляется свойство checked="checked" и визуально вариант чекнут.

Потом при определенных обстоятельствах я скрываю первый input в блоке и хочу чекнуть другой со значением "card". Для этого я пытаюсь сделтаь вот что:

```
$('input[value="card"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Это не работает. Точнее атрибут checked не изменяется у раиокнопок и при клике мыши. Меняется только визуально, а в коде - нет. Как это вообще работает и что отвечает за чекнутость радиобаттона?

Comment: в коде отвечает свойство .prop()

Comment: @DaemonHK prop действительно работает, спасибо. Еще бы понимать почему это так)

Comment: .attr() дает визуальное отображение, а .prop() отвечает за состояние элемента. По идее, нужно всегда .prop() использовать